# How many perfect matchings can I find in a wheel graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Firstly, the number of vertices have to be even. Also, I know the number of matchings on a complete graph of size $n$ is $(n-1)!!$. I'm not really sure how to approach counting matchings for wheel graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the center of the wheel has been matched with another vertex, the problem boils down to finding matchings for a line graph: that is a really trivial problem. A wheel graph over $2m$ vertices only has $2m-1$ perfect matchings. A wheel graph over $2m-1$ vertices has no perfect matching.

Comment: So I'm trying to understand how you came up with the answer. Firstly, there are $n$ vertices to map the center vertices to. Then would you just find the number of matchings for the line graph on $(n-1)$ vertices? Also wouldn't that mean $(2n-1)$ is odd and so you can't find any perfect matchings on odd vertices.

Comment: @AkashS: I am clearly assuming that the involved wheel graph has $2n$ vertices, hence the center can be matched with $2n-1$ vertices and the whole matching is fixed by such a choice.

Comment: If the involved wheel graph has $2n-1$ vertices there is no perfect matching, of course.

Comment: Aah so just to make sure I'm understanding this, we first match the center to $(2n-1)$ possible vertices and then now we have a line graph which has 0 possible matchings?

Comment: @AkashS: We have a wheel graph over $2m$ vertices; we match the center with something; it remains to find a perfect matching for a line graph over $2m-2$ vertices, and there is only one perfect matching for a line graph over $2m-2$ vertices. If the initial wheel graph has an odd number of vertices it does not make sense to even start the procedure, since a graph with an odd number of vertices has no perfect matching.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you so much. I was making a mistake while counting the matchings of the line graph.